# ATtiny USB data interrupt

Tags: usb, avr, atmel, attiny

I'm trying to use an ATtiny88 to detect data on a USB line. I have an USB data connection going to a hub and a secondary system and I want to use the ATtiny to detect if any peripheral hardware has been plugged into the USB port.

The idea is to simply the the USB D+ line and connect it to the ATtiny. When there is data on the line, the signal will pulse and this can be detected in the ATtiny.

Are there any electrical considerations I should take when doing so, or can I just connect the data line directly to the ATtiny?

Answer (score -1):

This is not remotely going to work.

The upstream side of your hub is not only all but certainly going to be using USB 2.0 High Speed (or even faster) signalling, but is going to have all of the traffic for the downstream devices intermixed together.

Not only would you need a way to tap the 480 megabit stream without electrically disturbing it, you would also need a way to parse and interpret it.  There are debug tools that do this, they are *not* inexpensive and they use things far more capable than a fifty cent microcontroller.

The only *realistic* solution to your need is going to be software on the host side.

Comment: I dont need to parse and interpret the data. I just need to know if there is any data. A detection if something is inserted, a keyboard as an example.